# multithreading on a web server C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

When you have a web app which uses a database as repository, all the DAL calls from the business logic aren't synchronized.

I know that each request is designated a thread for processing, which means that the db access is somehow multithreaded - but I have seen no synchronization code in the app and it magically works.

The question would be the following:

I have a business logic which calls a wrapper over some unmanaged code. Should the call to the unmanaged code be protected by some sync code? #

The unmanaged DLL is not multi-threaded. It accesses some files and it unpacks them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to synchronize the threads accessing a DATABASE, as it is one of the defining properties of a (non stone-age) DB to be "quite able of handling that, thank you".

Now by your definition your unmanaged DLL does not share this property, which means different rules apply or you will crash and burn.

There are many ways to achieve your goal, the most common being

- Synchronizing your web apps threads when calling in the DLL: Straight forward in coding, but has definitly to be researched in terms of webserver interaction (deadlock, thread starvation anyone?)
- Wrap your DLL in a different process with some sort of connection to it i.e. make your own "DLL server". More work, but maybe a more robust implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Time to learn the basics of databases?

Databases + Transactions - which are an inherent part of database basics - are doing the job for you. Databases per se are design around the concept if multiple users using them and enforcing ACID conditions, as well as synchronizing acess between multiple users.

Anything you do is worse than what they do. And without knowing it you use them inefficiently anyway.

Comment: i second that, plus, when you have a web server, each request gets it own thread and executed in a jail. OK then , when do you need synchronization? that is when you have shared objects across appdomain. then you need some kind of locking.

Comment: @TomTom However true, that really didn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that each request is designated a thread for processing, which
>   means that the db access is somehow multithreaded - but I have seen no
>   synchronization code in the app and it magically works.

I don't think that's accurate. The Thread's execution is halted until the DB call returns.

> I have a business logic which calls a wrapper over some unmanaged
>   code. Should the call to the unmanaged code be protected by some sync
>   code? #

It depends on whether multiple processes accessing the files in the unmanaged code is going to blow up or not. The issue would be data consistency and whether the files are opened in shared mode or not. Other than that, there's no need for syncing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the database code and most other web application related code already written for you handles the multithreading issues related to shared access of resources between threads, as long as the threads don't share any data in your *own* code (ie shared/static variables), you don't generally need to manually synchronize anything in your web application.

If you on the other hand import a native library that is not thread safe and want to call it from multiple threads, yes, you'll need to synchronize since it WILL be shared between all threads and - just like the pre written code is - would need to be thread aware to work transparently.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, your code is accessing the file system directly, then there's plenty of opportunity for collisions if the system is used by more than one user at a time. In this case, some sort of intermediate layer should synchronize disk access, which is one of the functions that the database server provides.

When you use a database such as MS SQL Server, the server takes care of keeping threads from stepping on each other, and acts as the gatekeeper to data in RAM and on disk. Unwisely locking tables, etc can cause errors, but it's rare in a properly structured application.

Answer (score 1):

There is generally no need for synchronization, because the database code tends to be blocking (it's synchronous).  There is typically no interaction between the database thread and the web thread, other than getting the results returned from the call.

Even if you use an asynchronous web thread, there is still no real interaction between the web thread and the database thread, so there is need to syncrhonize.